# Generate a code with a wizard on openERP 7

Tags: module, odoo, wizard, openerp-7

i'm new to openERP and I hadn't found an exhaustive and simple guide for wizards.
I have to do a wizard that generates a code by using the product_id.
This wizard have to generate the code of ***all*** the products when i click on it and put it in in the field EAN13. I have no idea how to create the wizard that take the code, generates his own code and put it in the field.
Sorry for my bad english :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check [OpenERP Technical Memento](https://www.odoo.com/files/memento/OpenERP_Technical_Memento_latest.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new memory model

```
class ean13_wiz(osv.osv_memory):
  _name = 'ean13.wiz'
  _description = 'EAN13 wizard'
  _columns = {
     'ean_template':fields.char('ean_template', size=13, required=True),
  }
 _defaults = {                 
     'ean_template': '2100000000000',
}

def ean13_logic(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):

  # your duplicate buziness logic
  ...
```

I added only 1 field for init the ean13 template

When you click on the submit button you should add the view xml action to your ean13_logic to add a ean to every product. maybe have some feedback how many are changed.

look at the link for more info: [wizard example](http://progressdll.roon.io/18-4-2014)